# Run script with rc.local: script works, but not at boot

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, boot, autorun

I have a node.js script which need to start at boot *and* run under the www-data user. During development I always started the script with:

```
su www-data -c 'node /var/www/php-jobs/manager.js
```

I saw exactly what happened, the manager.js works now great. Searching SO I found I had to place this in my `/etc/rc.local`. Also, I learned to point the output to a log file and to append the `2>&1` to "redirect stderr to stdout" and it should be a daemon so the last character is a `&`.

Finally, my `/etc/rc.local` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

su www-data -c 'node /var/www/php-jobs/manager.js >> /var/log/php-jobs.log 2>&1 &'

exit 0
```

If I run this myself (`sudo /etc/rc.local`): yes, it works! However, if I perform a reboot no `node` process is running, the `/var/log/php-jobs.log` does not exist and thus, the manager.js does not work. What is happening?

Comment: Does it work if you add `nohup(1)`? `su www-data -c 'nohup node /var/www/php-jobs/manager.js >> /var/log/php-jobs.log 2>&1 &'` Or do you need to give an absolute path to `node` because it isn't in the `PATH` that is used during early boot? `su www-data -c '/path/to/node /var/www/php-jobs/manager.js >> /var/log/php-jobs.log 2>&1 &'`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I have tried a) add nohup b) add absolute path /usr/bin/node and c) checked permissions of /var/log/php-jobs.log, they are set to www-data:www-data. After reboot, there is no `node` process (which is the case if I start it myself) and /var/log/php-jobs.log is empty. Thanks for the quick reply, other suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps add an `upstart` configuration file instead; [apparently it needs `HOME` to be configured](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/)?

Comment: I've changed to upstart, which does a better job. Problem is solved now :)

Comment: @JurianSluiman: perhaps answer your own question, sharing the upstart script so others can learn from your experience?

Comment: @sehe Will write an answer. With upstart I found another problem, solving that now and will finally post a complete solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with [upstart](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/), which works fine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes (and in this case, the link is broken so your answer is invalid).

Comment: The link doesn't work. As per http://upstart.ubuntu.com/: "Project is in maintaince mode only. No new features are being developed and the general advice would be to move over to another minimal init system or systemd."

Answer (score 73):

In this example of a rc.local script I use io redirection at the very first line of execution to my own log file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exec 1>/tmp/rc.local.log 2>&1  # send stdout and stderr from rc.local to a log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

/opt/stuff/somefancy.error.script.sh

exit 0
```

Comment: This didn't work. On startup, the log file wasn't created (but it was created when I ran the script manually).

Comment: debug facility worked very well in my case, thanks for the hint! id it doesn't work, make sure the `/tmp` directory exists and is writable (which should be the case in most normal circumstances).

Answer (score 12):

On some linux's (Centos & RH, e.g.), `/etc/rc.local` is initially just a symbolic link to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.  On those systems, if the symbolic link is broken, and `/etc/rc.local` is a separate file, then changes to `/etc/rc.local` won't get seen at bootup -- the boot process will run the version in `/etc/rc.d`.  (They'll work if one runs `/etc/rc.local` manually, but won't be run at bootup.)

Sounds like on dimadima's system, they are separate files, but `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` calls `/etc/rc.local`

The symbolic link from `/etc/rc.local` to the 'real' one in `/etc/rc.d` can get lost if one moves `rc.local` to a backup directory and copies it back or creates it from scratch, not realizing the original one in `/etc` was just a symbolic link.

Comment: This solved my problem. I had redirected `/etc/rc.local` to my own config file with a symlink. It worked fine when I ran it, but `/etc/rc.local` was not accessed on boot. I replaced `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` with a symlink to my config file and then reinstituted the default CentOS `/etc/rc.local` symlink to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu I noticed there are 2 files. The real one is `/etc/init.d/rc.local`; it seems the other `/etc/rc.local` is bogus?

Once I modified the correct one (`/etc/init.d/rc.local`) it did execute just as expected.

Comment: Skimming `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, it appears that `/etc/rc.local` is executed by the former.

Answer (score 4):

You might also have made it work by specifying the full path to node. Furthermore, when you want to run a shell command as a daemon you should close stdin by adding 1<&- before the &.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (on CentOS 7) and I fixed it by giving execute permissions to /etc/local:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using linux on cloud, then usually you don't have chance to touch the real hardware using  your hands.  so you don't see the configuration interface when booting for the first time, and of course cannot configure it. As a result, the `firstboot` service will always be in the way to `rc.local`. The solution is to disable `firstboot` by doing:

```
sudo chkconfig firstboot off
```

if you are not sure why your `rc.local` does not run, you can always check from `/etc/rc.d/rc` file because this file will always run and call other subsystems (e.g. rc.local).

Answer (score 1):

I got my script to work by editing `/etc/rc.local` then issuing the following 3 commands.

```
sudo mv /filename /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename 
sudo update-rc.d filename defaults
```

Now the script works at boot.

Comment: I put my script.sh in /etc/init.d, but its not executing at boot. could you tell me what to do edit in /etc/rc.local to work my scirpt.sh

Answer (score 1):

I am using CentOS 7.

```
$ cd  /etc/profile.d

$ vim yourstuffs.sh
```

Type the following into the yourstuffs.sh script.

type whatever you want here to execute

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Save and reboot the OS.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that these scripts are executed at login, rather than startup. They'll execute every time somebody logs in, and as that user, so for instance anything that requires `root`  won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have used rc.local in the past. But I have learned from my experience that the most reliable way to run your script at the system boot time is is to use **@reboot** command in crontab. For example:

```
@reboot path_to_the_start_up_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by a missing or incomplete PATH environment variable.

If you provide full absolute paths to your executables (su and node) it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that if you place your script in a certain RUN Level, you should use ln -s to link the script to the level you want it to work in.

Answer (score 0):

first make the script executable using
`sudo chmod 755 /path/of/the/file.sh`
now add the script in the rc.local 
`sh /path/of/the/file.sh`
before exit 0
in the rc.local,
next make the rc.local to executable with
`sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local`
next to initialize the rc.local use
`sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start`
this will initiate the rc.local
now reboot the system.
Done..

Answer (score 0):

I found that because I was using a network-oriented command in my `rc.local`, sometimes it would fail. I fixed this by putting `sleep 3` at the top of my script. I don't know why but it seems when the script is run the network interfaces aren't properly configured or something, and this just allows some time for the DHCP server or something. I don't fully understand but I suppose you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue, the script was running fine locally but when I reboot/power-on it was not.

I resolved the issue by changing the file path. Basically need to give the complete path in the script. While running locally, file can be accessed but when running on reboot, local path will not be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified you have systemd package installed? It's not default in all ubuntu versions.

```
sudo apt-get install systemd
sudo systemctl status rc-local
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

and a reminder to everyone else, first line **#!/bin/sh -e**  and last line **exit 0**

Answer (score -1):

## 1 Do not recommend using root to run the apps such as node app.

Well you can do it but may catch more exceptions.

## 2 The rc.local normally runs as root user.

So if the your script should runs as another user such as www U should make sure the PATH and other environment is ok.

## 3 I find a easy way to run a service as a user:

sudo -u www -i /the/path/of/your/script

Please prefer the sudo manual~
       -i [command]
                   The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a loginshell...

Answer (score -3):

`rc.local` only runs on startup.  If you reboot and want the script to execute, it needs to go into the `rc.0` file starting with the K99 prefix.