# Not writing to log - but only when started from rc.local

Tags: c, linux, logging, local, var

I have a simple C app running on both Ubuntu and Raspberry PI.

It need to write to a log file periodically and when run from the command line as root (or sudo) it creates / writes to the log file perfectly.

The log file is in /var/log/app-name/app-name.log (where app-name is the name of my app).

It first checks to see if the folder exists and if not then create it. It then opens the log file for create/append and outputs to it.

However, when I start the app from rc.local the app still does everything else perfectly, reading remote telnet servers, reads / writes to a local mysql database etc, but it never creates the /var/log folder or writes to the log file, even if it already exits (the fopen returns a 0).

I'm sure it's going to be something really simple, but I can't put my finger on it.

I've tried setuid etc and nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Testing & creating the folder for the log goes like this.  This works if run from the command line but failes when run from rc.local

```
void checkVarLogDir()
{
    struct stat st = {0};
    if (stat("/var/log/phone_log", &st) == -1) 
    {
        mkdir("/var/log/phone_log", 0744);
    }
}
```

Running from rc.local looking like this:

/path-to-app/phlog &

I could add the fopen/fwrite/fclose here as well but it's simple stuff that works when not run from rc.local.

Comment: post the code.  How can we be expected to debug the problem with out the code?  Are we to guess as to the code contents?  It would also be a good idea to post the part of the script of `rc.local` that starts the application.

Comment: this link is way to large to post here, but do read: <http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/>

Comment: this related question should lead you to the answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot>

Comment: Updated for more info

Comment: Put a `perror("/var/log/phone_log");` before and after the `mkdir` line and after `fopen` returns a 0, to let us know what errors occur.