# Script works fine normally but fails when executed from rc.local

Tags: mongodb, bash, centos

Based on the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot), I have the following `rc.local`

```
#!/bin/bash

#start script
exec 2> /scriptfolder/rc.local.log
exec 1>&2
set -x

/scriptfolder/startscript.sh

exit 0
```

Here is the specific line of `startscript.sh` that isn't working properly from `rc.local`

```
nohup sudo mongod --dbpath /scriptfolder/subfolder/ta_data/ --port 27027 --logRotate reopen --logappend --logpath /scriptfolder/autostart.mongod.log --fork &
```

I've also tried a few variants, including:

```
nohup sudo mongod --dbpath /scriptfolder/subfolder/ta_data/ --port 27027 &> /scriptfolder/autostart.mongod.log&
```

They all work when I run `./startscript.sh` manually but when it runs from `rc.local` mongo never starts.  Subsequent commands (including some docker commands) *do run*, so I know the script itself is executing.  I don't see any errors in `rc.local.log` and `autostart.mongod.log` is just empty.

Comment: Not sure why this got voted to close. Quite a mystery and I'm afraid I can't offer any ideas. Good luck!

Comment: I would have posted on linux.se except that I found the referenced question on SO which is almost identical and quite popular.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Oh, you already have `set -x` near the top of your script. If you use `set -vx` then you see the line or block of code without variables expected is show, and then you get the `set -x` view. Maybe that will illuminate something? Does the `rc.local` get `source` d? Could that be a cause (I don't see how for this case). Good luck.